# Where should i store my texture files in Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, image, file, import

The code I use to create textures looks like this:

```
GImage ballTexture = createTexture("ballTexture.png", (int) BALL_SIZE,
            (int) BALL_SIZE);
```

method:

```
private GImage createTexture(String importedImage, int width, int height) {
    Image importResult = getImage(getCodeBase(), importedImage);
    GImage textureResult = new GImage(importResult);
    textureResult.setSize(width, height);
    return textureResult;
```

My project file structure is this (Java is general folder for all projects):

[image]

I put 5 texture files inside `bin` folder after I found that  they were not imported otherwise (from different locations). I had a copy of 3 inside `PongGame`, and another copy inside `src` but those I did not update, and after i chose to rename my project with File -> Rename... and my `bin` folder was lost, 2 files were lost and 3 were replaced with outdated versions (i dont know which copy was used to replace those)

So my question would be: how should i properly store textures and then import them into my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you add it to your src folder it will be copied to the bin folder for you. Generally I make a res folder inside src to keep things more organized. Might not be best but it works.

Comment: I tried it now, and it works with textures in `src`, I have no idea why the images were not imported earlier